# Get actual count of matches in Azure Search

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

Azure Search returns a maximum of 1,000 results at a time. For paging on the client, I want the *total count* of matches in order to be able to display the correct number of paging buttons at the bottom and in order to be able to tell the user how many results there are. However, if there are over a thousand, how do I get the actual count? All I know is that there were *at least* 1,000 matches.

I need to be able to do this from within the SDK.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to get total number of documents in an index, one thing you could do is set [`IncludeTotalResultCount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.search.models.searchparameters.includetotalresultcount?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Search_Models_SearchParameters_IncludeTotalResultCount) to `true` in your search parameters. Once you do that when you execute the query, you will see the count of total documents in an index in [`Count`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.search.models.documentsearchresultbase-2.count?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Search_Models_DocumentSearchResultBase_2_Count) property of search results.

Here's a sample code for that:

```
        var credentials = new SearchCredentials("account-key (query or admin key)");
        var indexClient = new SearchIndexClient("account-name", "index-name", credentials);
        var searchParameters = new SearchParameters()
        {
            QueryType = QueryType.Full,
            IncludeTotalResultCount = true
        };
        var searchResults = await indexClient.Documents.SearchAsync("*", searchParameters);
        Console.WriteLine("Total documents in index (approx) = " + searchResults.Count.GetValueOrDefault());//Prints the total number of documents in the index
```

Please note that:

- This count will be approximate.
- Getting the count is an expensive operation so you should only do it with the very first request when implementing pagination.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on using it only on the first page of results. I'll just have IncludeTotalResultCount  = skip == 0.

Comment: In case others run into the same issue, the parameter name was changed to "includeTotalCount" as of 11.0.0 (according to the change log). As of this comment, most of the examples I see show the old parameter name, which returned "undefined" for count (as of 11.0.3, at least).

Answer (score 1):

For REST clients using the POST API, just include `"count": "true"` to the payload. You get the count in `@odata.count`.

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/search-documents