# Azure Search - Is the count approximate or real?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

I am with an Azure Search with around 615k docs. I am getting different counts when using $count when comparing with the previous search based on sql server. O the official doc I could not find any information about it, but here on StackOverflow I’ve found the following:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47089349

So is the $count approximate or real? Is there any information in the official doc about it that I’ve missed?

Comment: Are you checking $count in the response of a search request, or are you calling the docs/$count API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The count is approximate. From the [`REST API documentation page`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/search-documents):

> **$count=true | false**
>
> Optional, defaults to false. When calling via POST, this parameter is
>   named count instead of $count. Specifies whether to fetch the total
>   count of results. This is the count of all documents that match the
>   search and $filter parameters, ignoring $top and $skip. Setting this
>   value to true may have a performance impact. **Note that the count
>   returned is an approximation**. If you’d like to get only the count
>   without any documents, you can use $top=0

Comment: It seems that microsoft has adjusted the relevant sentence in the REST API documentation to: **Count is accurate if the index is stable, but will under or over-report any documents that are actively added, updated, or deleted.**

Answer (score 0):

The returned count is an approximation. Besides "REST API document", it's documented in "[.NET API document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.search.models.searchparameters.includetotalresultcount?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Search_Models_SearchParameters_IncludeTotalResultCount)" too.

Comment: yeap, but no info in here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-pagination-page-layout